# Update To Google API PHP Client Sponsered Tag Link

Tags: feature-request, sponsored-tags

The [google-api-php-client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-api-php-client) tag, being a sponsered tag, has some additional links across the top of the tag search inside the *"Sponsered links for this tag"* box. I noticed the [Project Page](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/) link navigates to a deprecated repository with an additional link to navigate to the active repository. I was wondering if this link could be updated to link to the active [GitHub](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) repository instead. The *"Getting Started"* link is still ok as it references an information page. I know in the grand scheme of things this is probably trivial but I just thought it may be nice to link interested users to the active repository instead of the old deprecated one if they're interested in learning about the project.

Comment: IIRC that's the responsibility of the sponsor.

Comment: @Stijn Oh, ok. Didn't know that. Sorry about that. Thanks for the heads up. Should I go ahead and delete this or did you want to post that as an answer?

Comment: I'm not sure, I just vaguely recall such a thing. You should leave it up so someone who is sure can answer :)

Comment: @Stijn Ok. Sounds good. Will do. Thank you for the response.

Comment: Also the case with the google-api-ruby-client sponsorship. Reaching out to the client (who is responsible for this content) now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just heard back from our contact at Google-- they gave the go-ahead to make this change.

This update is now live.

Thank you for spotting and suggesting this!